# Splitting a text file in half using PHP?

Tags: php, text

I want to take one text file, split it in half, and put one half in one file, then the remaining half in the next. How would one accomplish this?

an example would be: *split.php?n=file.txt*

```
$file = $_GET['n'];

$i = 1;
$fp = fopen("./server/php/files/".$file,'a+');
$fs = filesize("./server/php/files/".$file);
$lengthhalf = $fs / 2;
while(! feof($fp)) {
    $contents = fread($fp,$lengthhalf);
    file_put_contents('./server/php/files/[2]'.$file,$contents);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: I could use either, I just need to split half and half.

Comment: If the file is quite small, just use $file = filegetcontents(). Then just split the $variable half and use putfilecontents two times to write them to the disk.

Comment: unix-ish host? why not use `exec('split ...')`?

Comment: In any case, be careful with including the `$_GET` variable's value as the filename directly in the path string (using `exec` or otherwise). It should be sanitized so that it can't be hijacked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does the work, **without reading the whole file** (or half of it) **at once in memory**:

```
function split_in_halves($file, $half1, $half2) {
    $size = filesize($file);
    $fd = fopen($file, 'rb');

    stream_copy_to_stream($fd, fopen($half1, 'wb'), $size/2);
    stream_copy_to_stream($fd, fopen($half2, 'wb'));
}
split_in_halves('foo', '[1]foo', '[2]foo');
```